# Remounting a part of external SD card

Tags: root-access, external-sd, mount, media-scanner

*Context: I've now spent more than 6 hours reading all articles / possible solutions I can find about the ".nomedia" file bug of Android 4+. See [bug report here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37199) or [also here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24162) or possible [solution here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/31110/2/media/java/android/media/MediaScanner.java). In short : for users with more than 10k media files on their microSD card (i have a 128 gb µSD!), the phone will be very hot at boot during 20 minutes / overheat / high cpu usage / fast battery drain ! Reason : Android 4+ doesn't care correctly about the ".nomedia" file like it did in Android 2.3, and the media scanner tries to browse all the files!*

I'm looking for a workaround for this problem. Question :

**Is it possible to remount a specific folder `myfolder` of my external SD card to `/mypersonalfolder/` and hide it from `/mnt/extSDcard/myfolder` .**

Or

**Is it possible, after boot, to `chmod` a specific folder from external SD card so that the media scanner won't be allowed to browse it?**

I have  a rooted Android 4.2.2

Comment: 1. Remounting will work, but hiding not. You may try to rename it to `.myfolder` (a dot indicates hidden) 2. `chmod` is not available on fuse, FAT or any other file system especially for external SD cards on Android (a custom kernel with explicit ext3/4 may work, but only when not using fuse)

Comment: `.myfolder` : already tried : doesn't work, the media scanner still parses it. 1. how to remount ?

Comment: depends, usually `mount --bind /path/to/myfolder /path/to/mypersonalfolder`. But remember, it's available at *both*  locations.

Comment: @GiantTree : hum then... I'm stuck again...  Here's what I need to do : `/mnt/extSdCard` available as usual to user `uO_a26` (that owns the media scanner : `android.process.media`)   but `/mnt/extSdCard/myfolder` *NOT*  available to `uO_a26` .

Comment: @GiantTree : Nota Bene: `drwxrwxr-x system   media_rw          2016-07-30 03:07 extSdCard`

Comment: That's not possible because of how the file system works. fuse simply relays the file system (FAT32) with a common user and group. FAT32 does not store any information about owner or permissions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43234/discussion-between-basj-and-gianttree).